# Can I achieve Natural Sorting on a VARCHAR field which contains various length alphanumeric values?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to write a MySQL query which will allow me to achieve natural sorting on a `VARCHAR` product code field containing various string lengths and formatted values.

I have tried many of the techniques found searching Stack Overflow but I can't get any to work for my scenario:

`product_code` (Sample Data)

```
BA112
BA113
BA27
BA12
112
998
BA113[1]
BA113[2]
```

Should sort to:

```
112
998
BA12
BA27
BA112
BA113
BA113[1]
BA113[2]
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: If the prefix is always 2 characters in length (or always 'BA') then it's easy, otherwise...

Answer (score 0):

The way you have described the results, the following will work:

```
order by length(product_code), product_code;
```

If you specifically want the numbers to appear first and they can be longer, then:

```
order by (product_code like REGEXP '^[0-9]*') desc
         length(product_code),
         product_code
```

Answer (score 0):

The only answer I can find now is ordering by string length first and alphanumerically then:

```
ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(product_code), product_code
```

But I think that your BA27 is really like "BA" and "27" and you want to order it by alphabetic first and numerid then, isn't it?

If so, you should store the alphabetic and the numeric part in different fields.

Remember to use `CHAR_LENGTH()` MySQL function, specially if you are using UTF encoding, because of the multi-byte characters (like "Ñ" or "¿").

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

select product_code 
from sample_data 
order by (concat(space(10-length(product_code)),product_code)) asc

The important part being the order by (concat...

Makes all values 10 characters long with spaces padded to the left.